# MATLAB: replace part of the string within specific format

Tags: regex, matlab, text

I have following format:

```
some text, <Parameter location> - parameter name, <Parameter location2> - parameter name2, Parameter location3> - parameter name3, ...
```

Where Parameter location can be any combination of chars, numbers and / character.

I'd like to change the string so that the output would be  like

```
some text, parameter name, parameter name2, parameter name3,
```

Please assist :)

Comment: the text is from some logs - it contain some parameter location: which I don't care - the unimportant text and the parameter name - what I'm looking for

Comment: I've updated the example. hope that this one is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

```
str = 'some text, <Parameter location> - parameter name, <Parameter location2> - parameter name2, Parameter location3> - parameter name3';
newStr = regexprep(str, '\,.*?-', ',');
```

Comment: For the input you have specified it produces the output you sepcified :)

Comment: it didn't removed the < >

Comment: It is impossible. With this input it produces the needed output. Please show on which input do you try it?